how to find the right URL for API Gateway API
In CDK (Typescript) I am creating a Lambda with an API Gateway in front of it.
The AWS console shows me something called an “Invoke URL”, something like https://wi4a95skjk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod and it works fine, exactly what I need.
Then I try to attach my custom URL to it, like this:
 const certificate = Certificate.fromCertificateArn(
    scope,
    `${id}-cert`,
    props.certificateArn
  );

  const domainName = this.addDomainName(`${id}-dn`, {
    domainName: `${props.subDomainName}.${props.domainName}`,
    certificate,
  });

  const zone = HostedZone.fromLookup(this, `${id}-hz`, {
    domainName: props.domainName,
  });
  new ARecord(this, `${id}-arecord`, {
    zone,
    recordName: props.subDomainName,
    target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new ApiGateway(this)),
    ttl: Duration.minutes(3),
  });

This successfully creates an A record in the zone, that looks like this:
mysub.example.org   A   Simple  -   Yes d-ywfxof47wi.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.

(Note that the — represents a TTL that for some reason is unset.)
My URL mysub.example.org and the d-ywfx... nonsense (which point to different IP address) both just hang and do nothing when I try to access them with curl.
What is going wrong here?
Edit:: now I am getting {"message":"Forbidden"}% from the d-y url; my own is still hanging.


My URL mysub.example.org ... just hangs and does nothing

Hmmm, I see no smoking gun.  Your CDK code includes the necessary pieces.  Your Hosted Zone Alias Record points to an API Gateway Domain Name.  Double-check the referenced certificate and hosted zone resources.  Your existing certificate is referenced by ARN with fromCertificateArn, the value of which the CDK does not verify.  Your existing Hosted Zone info is referenced with fromLookup, which the CDK fetches once with an SDK call and then caches.  Check cdk.context.json to be sure the cached zone values are current.

I am getting {"message":"Forbidden"}% from the d-y url;

This is expected.  It's the "API Gateway Domain Name" value, not a publicly available endpoint.  See below.

Note that the — represents a TTL that for some reason is unset.

This is expected. As the docs say: "If an alias record points to an AWS resource, you can't set the time to live (TTL); Route 53 uses the default TTL for the resource. "

Here's a recap:
API Gateway Domain Name

CDK: domainName prop on RestApi
CloudFormation:  AWS::ApiGateway::DomainName resource
Console:  API Gateway > Endpoint Configuration > Custom Domain Names
Docs:  Routing traffic to an Amazon API Gateway API by using your domain name, and Setting up a regional custom domain name in API Gateway

An "API Gateway domain name" is consumed as the value of the Hosted Zone's Alias record (see below).  It has the format d-73loomnpd7.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com.  It's not a publicly exposed.
Route 53 Alias Record

CDK: route53.ARecord construct
CloudFormation:  AWS::Route53::RecordSet resource
Console:  Route 53 > Hosted Zones > Records
Docs: Choosing between alias and non-alias records

Has the information shown in the question.  The value references the API Gateway domain name (see above).
API Gateway Default Endpoint

CDK: the api.url property on the Rest API construct.
CloudFormation:  n/a
Console:  API Gateway > API Settings > Default Endpoint

The Default Endpoint is the publicly accessible endpoint.  It's the https://wi4a95skjk.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod you note in your question, where the wi4a95skjk prefix is the Rest API ID (CDK api.apiId property) and the /prod/ path is the stage.  You probably want to disable the default endpoint because you have (hopefully ) a custom domain in front of the API.  In the CDK, you'd do this with disableExecuteApiEndpoint: true on the RestAPI construct.
// Tip: print the URL to the console at deploy time
new cdk.CfnOutput(this, "RestApiUrl", { value: api.url ?? "DISABLED",});


Sorry, after 3 hours of swearing, I realize there was a slight typo in my test.  I was setting permissions on my gateway — and then trying to access the Cloudfront URL.  My fault, almost totally.  (I say “almost” because the baroque dog-patch that is AWS gives just so many places to look...
